# When finding targets in a trade war, does the goods balance or trade balance matter more?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, balance-of-trade, free-trade

By most measures, most people who look at trade balance, but it might include a good chunk of services imports/exports who might not be as readily subjected to tariffs.